# Best practice when using seed.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, seed

I'm having some difficulties understanding how to use the `seed.rb` script in rails.

So far, I've used it to populate my database every time i deploy my application.

Like this.

**seed.rb**

```
["Video", "Tv"].each do |thing|
  Category.create(name: thing)
end
```

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

The script can now be runned every deploy or pull.
Anyone in the dev team can now add their own category without have to worry about duplications.

Like this.

**Person one**

- Adding the `Table` category to `seed.rb`.
- Commit and push to master.

**Person two**

- Pull master.
- Run `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:seed` to ensure that the local database is up-to-date.
- Deploy application to production server. `rake db:seed` is being runned on the server to ensure an up-to-date database.

Is this workflow okay, if not, where should I put the new data to ensure that every developer has an up-to-date database?

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend writing your seed so that it can be run more than once without trying to create duplicate categories...

```
["Video", "Tv"].each do |thing|
  Category.find_or_create_by_name(thing)
end
```

Comment: Using one field was just an example. I could for example have a `active` filed in the table. The `active` field might change during runtime, which means that running `Category.find_or_create_by_name_and_active(name, active)` might create duplications.

Comment: If the unique attribute is `name` then you do...

    `["Video", "Tv"].each do |name|
      category = Category.find_or_initialize_by_name(name)
      category.update_attributes(...)
    end`